# Where do business logic methods go in a layered application using entity framework 6 with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with Entity Framework 6 and .NET 4.5.2.  I am building a WinForms application.  I have structured my application in a layered fashion as follows:

Solution name is TrackingSystem.

Projects under the solution are:

- TrackingSystem.UI (dependent on Domain Layer)
- TrackingSystem.Domain (dependent on DAL)
- TrackingSystem.DomainClasses (no dependencies)
- TrackingSystem.DAL (no dependencies)

The TrackingSystem.DomainClasses project contains several class definitions which were generated from the Entity Framework Power Tools add-on.  These are plain and simple POCO style files. Just the class name and properties for each domain entity. Example:

```
Public class Location
{
  int locationId {get;set;}
  string businessName {get;set;}
  string cityLoc {get;set;}
  string stateLoc {get;set}
  string zipCodeLoc {get;set;}
}
```

I reference the TrackingSystem.DomainClasses project in my TrackingSystem.UI  project and include it in the uses statement of my WinForms code area.  I have it setup this way so I don’t expose all of the classes and methods in my domain layer.

The question I have now is the placement of requests for the various entities.  For example, Let’s say I want to add a request as follows:

```
public List<Location> getAllLocations();
```

I don’t want to add this to the Location class in the  TrackingSystem.DomainClasses  project because those classes are to be simple POCOs.

Since this is something the domain would provide after asking the DAL I do want it to be in a class under the TrackingSystem.Domain project.  This is where I am not sure how to proceed.  I could create a class under the TrackingSystem.Domain project called Location but then I would have a duplicate class name in the solution. So maybe I could name it LocationServices where I can add requests related to the Location entity.  If I do this I’m not sure if this should be at the root of the TrackingSystem.Domain project or perhaps under a folder called DomainEntityServices. Wherever I put it that would be the place I would create similar classes for requests related to other classes (i.e. ProductServices).

I would appreciate some ideas here as to how others may be setting this up or if there is a guidelines document some place that addresses how to setup a Visual Studio project for layered solutions.  Thanks in advance.

UPDATED DESCRIPTION 11/21/2015 7:11 AM
I found an example project which shows one case where the POCO and implementation code were placed in the project.  In this case, the POCOs and BLL were in separate projects but they retained the same entity name. In this case a Customer.cs file existed in the POCOs project and BLL project where the BLL project contained the implementation while the POCO project just POCO content. The sample project is at the below URL:

```
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Multilayered-Architecture-703a0d69
```

UPDATED DESCRIPTION 11/20/2015 1:36 PM
In particular, I am looking for what to do when the requested service can be answered in the domain without asking the DAL such as the following business rule: The City must be San Bernardino.  In this case, where in the domain do I put this rule check which does not require checking with the DAL? Do I create a new class like LocationServices which would have the logic to check this rule and if so where would the class be placed in a Visual Studio project considering where my projects already are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation I'd have an interface in the domain

```
public interface IAmALocationsRepository 
{
   List<Location> getAllLocations(); 
}
```

In your domain you use this interface.

In your DAL you implement it

```
public class LocationsRepository : IAmALocationsRepository 
{
   public List<Location> getAllLocations()
   {
     //do things here
   }
}
```

This way your domain says it is possible for there to be a list of locations that I can use but I don't care where it comes from.

And your DAL provides the list without the domain being aware.

Comment: Looks like you are saying that I would need an Interface for any service performed by the DAL for the Domain layer? That is interesting. I think My question was not structured right.  I will update it.  Meanwhile, what about non data related services to be performed by the Domain such as a business rule  (i.e. The city must be San Bernardino)? Where would those types of methods go which would not need to contact the DAL? I attempted to guess possible project places but am looking for suggestions.

Comment: yep, the domain code shouldn't need any external resources to run. so it provides interfaces that others can implement.

Comment: I tend to loosely group things as domain services (i.e. they don't require an external resource) and application services (they do require an external resource). You can think of the DAL as an application service that translates between persistence and domain

Comment: I also tend not think in terms of layers but instead hexagonal architecture (or ports & adapters). http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture

Comment: I found a sample MSDN project which shows where to place the POCOs and implementation files for an entity. I updated the question to include the URL for the sample I found.  I am closing out this question now. Thank you everyone for your very helpful feedback.